# FormatException: Invalid date format flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, date

Basically when the api pass the date in an invalid format, then it should not crash and the field should display empty

Exception has occurred.
FormatException (FormatException: Invalid date format
NaNNaNNa)

I also try{}catch(e) but the error still shows up

```
  String formattedDate(String date) {
    if (date.length >= 8) {
      final dateTime = DateTime.tryParse('${date.substring(0, 8)}T${date.substring(8)}');
      if (dateTime != null) {
        return DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(dateTime).toString();
      }
    }
    return '';
  }
}
  void loadTravellerIntoForm(TravellerProfile? traveller) {
    String formattedPassportExpiry = '';

    if (traveller?.passportExpiry != null &&
        traveller?.passportExpiry?.isNotEmpty == true) {
      formattedPassportExpiry = DateFormat('dd MMM yyyy').format(
          DateTime.parse(traveller?.passportExpiry?.substring(0, 8) ?? ''));
    }
    
    passportExpiryDateTextCtrl.text = formattedPassportExpiry;
...}
```

```
_TravellerCard(
              ...
              expiryDate: controller.formattedDate(detail.passportExpiry ?? ''),
```

````
Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError: FormatException: Invalid date format
8 Apr 20. Error thrown while handling a gesture.
       at DateTime.parse(dart:core)
       at MyTravellersCtrl.loadTravellerIntoForm(my_travellers_ctrl.dart:298)
       at _MyTravellersView.build.<fn>.<fn>(my_travellers_page.dart:168)
       at _TravellersListView.build.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>(my_travellers_page.dart:752)
       at _InkResponseState.handleTap(ink_well.dart:1154)
       at GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback(recognizer.dart:275)
       at TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp(tap.dart:654)
       at BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp(tap.dart:311)
       at BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture(tap.dart:281)
       at GestureArenaManager.sweep(arena.dart:167)
       at GestureBinding.handleEvent(binding.dart:492)
       at GestureBinding.dispatchEvent(binding.dart:468)
       at RendererBinding.dispatchEvent(binding.dart:333)
       at GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately(binding.dart:413)
       at GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent(binding.dart:376)
       at GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue(binding.dart:323)
       at GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket(binding.dart:292)```
````

Comment: Did you previously use DateTime.parse? Maybe you just need to hot restart?

Comment: can you provide more code, such as the model or the fetch method, so we can get more idea about the issue.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan I tried that few times, still the same

Comment: @HamouOuyaba I have added additional code but I wasn't sure which one to put. I'm still new to this

Comment: @grizzzzzy post logcat error here and attach the api response

Comment: @Quicklearner done added in the post

Comment: @grizzzzzy Also add the response which is returning from api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void loadTravellerIntoForm(TravellerProfile? traveller) {
  String formattedPassportExpiry = '';

  if (traveller?.passportExpiry != null &&
      traveller?.passportExpiry?.isNotEmpty == true) {
    final parsedDate = DateTime.tryParse(traveller?.passportExpiry?.substring(0, 8) ?? '');
    if (parsedDate != null) {
      formattedPassportExpiry = DateFormat('dd MMM yyyy').format(parsedDate);
    } else {
      // Handle the date format exception here
      formattedPassportExpiry = ''; // Set to an empty string or handle it as needed
    }
  }

  passportExpiryDateTextCtrl.text = formattedPassportExpiry;
}
```

try this and let me know, if the issue is still there.

Answer (score 0):

The error is from the line below:

```dart
if (traveller?.passportExpiry != null &&
    traveller?.passportExpiry?.isNotEmpty == true) {
  formattedPassportExpiry = DateFormat('dd MMM yyyy').format(
      DateTime.parse(traveller?.passportExpiry?.substring(0, 8) ?? '')); // this line
}
```

Using null-aware operator (`?.`) might seems like it will prevent exceptions, but in fact, if `traveller` and `passportExpiry` are both not null, the value is evaluated to the `parse` method, and if the format happens to be invalid, it will throw `FormatException`.

You might want to change it to this:

```dart
if (traveller?.passportExpiry != null &&
    traveller?.passportExpiry?.isNotEmpty == true) {
  final passportExpiryDate = DateTime.tryParse(traveller?.passportExpiry?.substring(0, 8));
  if (passportExpiryDate != null) {
    formattedPassportExpiry = DateFormat('dd MMM yyyy').format(passportExpiryDate);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says that `traveller?.passportExpiry?.substring(0, 8)` actually is `8 Apr 20`. Which is not an accepted format for `DateTime.parse(`. For that you would need to do `DateFormat('dd MMM yyyy').parse(` instead. But the thing is this is already the format that you would like to have so it seems the entire conversion is unnecessary